# Story about an alien virus & a hidden space ship in a desert

Tags: story-identification, aliens, alien-invasion

I am trying to remember a story about a space ship watching over us for quite a few centuries. It offered its help when an alien virus was about to attack and wipe out the planet. It made its journey with a selected million of people under a lady commander for another Earth-like planet in a distant corner of space.

During this voyage the ship experimented on a girl to find the super extraordinary, the *incarnated one*, who was going to guide the whole entourage to this impossible goal.

A televised series has probably already been made.

Comment: a televised series has already been made probably...

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable. Please let me know if everything is ok. Also, try to add more details like when/where you read it, which language etc.

Comment: When did you read this?  Was it an English language story?

Comment: @jenayah, I've rejected your edits for a couple of reasons; Firstly that they make *material changes* to what OP is asking (for example "on a girl" becomes "on girls") and secondly, you've introduced grammatical errors that weren't there before

Comment: Hi there! :) I've edited your question a bit but some parts I had doubt about, especially if the ship experimented on girlS or on a single girl. Could you take a look and assert than my edit does not change what you meant? Also, here's [a guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) of things you might add to improve your question and have more chances of someone finding the book - it is a book, right?

Comment: @Valorum yeah, as I was editing it it was still "this voyage ship experimented on girl to find the super extraordinary" (before Loki's edit, who added the "a") so I wasn't sure, as I said in my previous comment. Statistically speaking, if you're looking for "the One" you probably experience on several girls, at least that was my thinking :) as for the errors, well, here's what I get for being cocky and editing a question not written in my first language. :p